# Using pipes in C: two child processes

Tags: c, pipe, exec, unistd.h

I'm attempting to simulate the following commands "ls | sort -r > text" in C using pipes.

I have my two child processes created using fork() and have used dup2() for changing the input/output

My issue now is correctly executing these commands. However, I'm a bit confused as to where each process must be run.

Is it as follows:
1) "ls" be executed in the parent
2) "sort -r" executed in child 1
3) "> text" executed in child 2

I'm currently attempting to run it as shown below:

```
execlp("ls", "ls", NULL); // this in child 1 block of code
execlp("sort -r > text", "sort -r > text", NULL); // this in child 2 block
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Neither process runs in the parent.  You fork two children, and setup their output streams: child 1 inherits stdin from the parent (the parent doesn't change it) and has its stdout dup'd to the write side of the pipe.  child 2 gets its stdin dup'd to the read side of the pipe, and its stdout directed to the file.  The parent closes both of its ends of the pipe. child 1 then execs 'ls', and child 2 exec 'sort -r'.

Comment: I see, that makes sense! In regards to executing both programs in the child processes, which exec function makes more sense? I'm trying 'execlp("ls",...) and 'execlp("sort -r",...) but doesn't seem to run properly.

Comment: execlp takes the command as its first arg, and then the list of arguments.  So you're looking for `execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);` and `execlp("sort", "sort", "-r", NULL);`